# Call a stored procedure every 5 seconds in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a stored procedure in MySQL and I want to execute it every 5 seconds, but when I simply run the stored procedure, it doesn't add any records to another table. But if I run the query separately, it works fine but in stored procedure it doesn't.

And how can I call it every 5 seconds.

Here is the stored procedure

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE ctrdata2.call_detail() 
begin
  INSERT INTO ctrdata2.reporting_call_detail 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   ctrdata2.call_detail 
  WHERE  EXISTS 
         ( 
                SELECT end_time 
                FROM   ctrdata2.transactions_reporting_call_detail 
                WHERE  call_detail.initiationtimestamp > transactions_reporting_call_detail.end_time);
END
```

Comment: Create an `event` instead of a `procedure`

Comment: @juergend still 0 row effected

Comment: Of course - that was only the part to execute it every 5 seconds. To see why it does not insert you have to check yout select query. it does not return anaything

Comment: @juergend i have check my query and run separately it works fine

Comment: Convert your SP to event procedure and set its scheduling to needed running frequence. Do not forget to enable Event scheduler.

Comment: INSERT INTO ctrdata2.reporting_call_detail 
  SELECT *  - this is bad practice specify the columns to be populated  and the columns to populate from

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the below code too.

```
CREATE EVENT runEveryFiveSeconds
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 SECOND
      DO
        CALL ctrdata2.call_detail();
```

Comment: should run this separately or in the same store procedure?

Comment: @Tayyab This statement is executed separately and once. Additionally - check that Event Scheduler is enabled. Also ensure that the SP needs less than 5 sec. for to be executed...